# How do i group and join results of the same result set returned from SQL Server from LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following data structure

[image]

In a Customer report, there are multiple orders from different clients and each order there are one to many items. When I execute my stored procedure, the data 
it returns in the result set has the above structure (note: there are duplicates in the query because one order has many items). There is a column 
called `ReportSequence` this is the order of appearance of the record on the report.

```
public class CustomerReport
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }     //maps to the CustomerId column in SQL Query result
    public string FirstName { get; set; }   //maps to the FName column
    public string LastName { get; set; }    //maps to the LName column
    public DateTime? ReportDate { get; set; }  //Generated at object creation
    public List<SaleOrder> SalesOrders { get; set; }  //see SaleOrder class

    public CustomerReport()
    {
        SalesOrders = new List<SaleOrder>();
    }
}
```

```
public class SaleOrder
{
    public int? SaleOrderId { get; set; }       //maps to the SalesOrderId column in sql query result 
    public string SaleOrderNumber { get; set; }  // maps to SalesOrderNumber column

    public List<SalesOrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }  //see SalesOrderItem class
    public int? SaleOrderTypeId { get; set; }     //maps to SalesOrderTypeId column
    public int? ReportSequenceNo { get; set; } //the sequence order 1,2,3... how each Sales Order appears on the report

    public SaleOrder()
    {
        OrderItems = new List<SalesOrderItem>();
    }
}
```

```
public class SalesOrderItem
{
    public int? ItemTypeId { get; set; }  //maps to ItemTypeId column in sql query result 
    public int? ItemId { get; set; }      // maps to ItemId column
    public string ItemName { get; set; }  //maps to ItemName column
}
```

Using the result returned by query execution (show on Excel screenshot), I need to generate the following JSON structure:

```
    {
        "CustomerId" : "10001",
        "FirstName" : "Nicholas",
        "LastName" : "Cage",
        "ReportDate" : "toays date",
        SalesOrders: [
            { 
                SaleOrderId : 6 , 
                SaleOrderNumber : "EB100X100" ,
                SaleOrderTypeId : 102, 
                ReportSequenceNo : 1, 
                SalesOrderItems : [
                    { ItemTypeId : NULL, ItemId :  NULL, ItemName : Null }
                ]  
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
```

The method I followed is:

First I have tried to build two sets of data from one set

1. The original result set was grouped by `SalesOrderId`
2. The above was joined with the original

But joining failed ... could not join them....

How do I build this JSON structure from Linq using above resultset and classes?

Comment: Excel Spreadsheets are not results from LINQ - can you show the actual LINQ query / result?

Answer (score -1):

all right, what you need here is the proper grouping of the source data.

```
allRecords.GroupBy(a=>a.CustomerId).Select(b=> new CustomerReport(b.Key){ 
SalesOrders = b.Values.GroupBy(c=>c.SaleOrderId).Select(d=> new SaleOrder(d.Key).........)}
```

It is not complete but I hope gives you a hint

Comment: .....now i'm really lost....what is b.key you pass to CustomerReport?

Comment: `x` should probably be `b` instead?

Comment: indeed it should have been "b", I adjusted the snippet